# How solved "ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead."?

Tags: python, classification, overfitting, python-3.x, k-nn

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkmacosx import Button
top = Tk()
top.title("Jobs")
top.geometry("1000x800")

line1 = LabelFrame(top, text='')
line1.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')

n = StringVar()

categorychoosen = ttk.Combobox(line1, width = 27, textvariable = n)


# Adding combobox drop down list
categorychoosen['values'] = ('Advocate','Arts','Automation Testing','Blockchain','Business Analyst',
                             'Web Designing')
  
categorychoosen.place(x=50, y=150)
categorychoosen.current()



    name=Label(line3,text="Welcom to ... company",font =("Arial", 10))
name.place(x=0, y=0)

n1 = StringVar()
sectionchoosen = ttk.Combobox(line3, width = 27, textvariable = n1)
  
# Adding combobox drop down list
sectionchoosen['values'] = (' Computer Science', 
                          ' computer engineering',
                          ' Information Technology',
                          ' artificial intelligence',
                          ' cyber security',
                          ' computer networks',
                          ' Information Security',
                          ' Management Information Systems',
                          ' Software engineering',
                          ' data analysis',
                          ' Data Science')
  
sectionchoosen.place(x=20, y=20)
sectionchoosen.current()

def model():
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    from scipy.sparse import hstack
    from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    import numpy as np



    Category= ['Advocate','Arts','Automation Testing','Web Designing']
    job = categorychoosen.get()
    section = sectionchoosen.get()
    expert = expertchoosen.get()
    language = languagechoosen.get()

    # transform 
    p = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

    target= p.fit_transform(Category)
    target.shape
    wordOfjob = p.fit_transform(job)
    wordOfsection = p.fit_transform(section)
    
    #zip
    features = list(zip(wordOfjob,wordOfsection))

   # train_test_split
   x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features,target ,random_state = 42, test_size = 0.2)

   # Knn Classifier                       
   model = OneVsRestClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric= 'euclidean'  ))
   model.fit(x_train,y_train)
   prediction = model.predict(x_test)

   # Result in GUI_Lable 
   jobResult = Label(line4,text=str(prediction) ,bg='light gray')
   jobResult.place(x=0, y=80)


but= Button(line4,text="Start",bg='gray', command=model)

but.place(x=0, y=120)



top.mainloop()
```

have a problem with the error, when I execute this code, it appears like this:`raise ValueError( ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead.`.

note:`categorychoosen` and `sectionchoosen`  its Combobox in GUI python

I searched a lot and concluded that this error is always from the line `model.fit(x_train,y_train)`, but I tried the solutions offered on the Internet, but no correction occurred to me. please help me. Even after adding me to `target.shape`. I get the same error. The error starts when the button is pressed in the interface, i.s. when the function `def model()` is started

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't understand everything in your code especially the interface stuff, but on ML side this code seems very strange to me, I think that there are lots of problems in the preparation of the data and this could explain why `fit` doesn't work. First, could you please shortly explain what you're trying to do? What are the instances, how many there are? The most obvious problem is that you're encoding everything with `LabelEncoder` (not correct for features), and additionally you're using the same instance `p` so this cannot work.

Comment: Text needs to be encoded before being fed to the ML model, but first we need to clarify what is the design of your task here. Currently for the target apparently you just create 3 instances for 3 different categories, I don't know what `get` returns but probably a single element, right? at first sight all this doesn't make sense, the model needs to be trained on multiple instances.